# How can I programmatically open a new CMD window that starts a subsytem linux shell and execute a script?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
cmd /K /IN-NEW-WINDOW C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -- /bin/script.sh
```

1. open a new CMD window,
2. that starts a WSL shell, and
3. executes a command

Comment: It is in the question... that is how far I got initially. Thanks for the down vote ;D

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a batch file (ex `open-cmds.bat`)

```
start C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -i -c 'cd ~/; ./my-script.sh'
```

I added the `cd ~/` in the example to emphasize that by starting the shell from `cmd` makes it have a different start location, ie `/mnt/c/...`

If you need more than the bash shell (app binaries, bash profile etc) You want to look into starting it as a login shell.

```
start C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -l -c './my-script.sh'
```

Comment: Don't name it `start.bat`, this may cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Also, `cmd /K` is unnecessary, and `-c` is expected to be *after* `-l`.

Comment: updated to reflect the improvements in the comments